# Spring-boot project, using Gradle, coded in Kotlin, auto-generate OpenAPI kotlin classes

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, gradle, openapi-generator

Problem: Generated sources are not picked up by gradle as part of the sources, thus importing the generated interfaces fails.

Question: how to add the generated sources so that gradle(with goovy dsl and kotlin plugin) picks them up?

setup:
spring-boot -> kotlin programming language
gradle -> groovy

I can generate the kotlin classes with [OpenAPI Generator Gradle Plugin](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator) with no problems.

I am using the option "interfaceOnly", so it only creates interfaces. That means I do need to implement those.

I am using the typical gradle project setup. Now I have no idea where to place the generated files so that gradle(and intellj) pick them up.

openAPI.yaml:

```
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  version: 0.1.0
  title: Villagechatter Calendar
  description: Villagechatter calendar microservice

tags:
  - name: external
    description: external API
  - name: internal
    description: Internal API for other microservices

paths:
  /hello:
    get:
      responses:
        200:
          description: Ok
          content:
            text/plain:
              schema:
                type: string
                description: demo
                example: Hello World!
```

build.gradle:

```
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.3.1.RELEASE"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.9.RELEASE"
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm" version "1.3.72"
    id "org.openapi.generator" version "4.3.1"
}
apply plugin: 'kotlin'

group = "com.example"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = ["-Xjsr305=strict"]
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}


openApiGenerate {
    inputSpec = "$rootDir/specs/openApi.yaml"
    generatorName = "kotlin-spring"
    //setting package names and interface only with a configFile, should not matter for the problem
    outputDir = "$buildDir/generated-src"
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
        exclude group : "org.junit.vintage"
        exclude module : "junit-vintage-engine"
    }
}
```

what I have tried:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        kotlin.srcDirs += "PATH-TO-GENERATED-FILES"
    }
}
```

Also tried creating a new sourceSet and adding it to the compileKotlin task

The google results I found were all about gradle and the kotlin dsl, sorry if this is a duplicate, I have not found the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve like this:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir("$buildDir/generated-src")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to auto generate them and put use them as sources in the project? Why not generate them into the project directory directly?

`outputDir = "$projectDir"`